# Carrying out a SUMIF like operation using SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm trying to produce a conditional sum in SQL Server Report Builder 3.0.

My expression looks like this:

```
=Sum(Iif(Fields!ProjectTypeID.Value=2,Fields!kWp.Value,0))
```

I'd hoped that this expression would produce a sum of the kWp of all projects of type 2.

Unfortunately, it is not to be. And I can't seem to work out why. It just returns a 0 result, even though I know that there are non-zero values in the kWp column, and the column does not contain nulls.

A colleague did manage to get a positive result by replacing the

```
Fields!kWp.Value
```

with

```
1 * Fields!kWp.Value
```

But we have no idea why this works, and therefore, can't really trust the answer.

How can I get this conditional sum to behave itself?

Comment: Do you have any decimal values stored in the column kWp ?

Comment: Yes - they're all decimal values - roughly in the range 0 - 100

Comment: Then you need to cast the values into int  SUM(iif(Fields!ProjectTypeID.Value = 2,CINT(Fields!FieldkWp.Value),0)

Comment: Won't this throw away the fractional part, though? These are significant, and I don't want to round down all the 3.4 to 3, etc.

Comment: So better convert every thing to decimal  SUM(iif(Fields!ProjectTypeID.Value = 2,cdbl(Fields!FieldkWp.Value),0.00)

Comment: Great - thanks! Can you make this into an answer so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The data type of the column 'kWp' is Decimal so you need to either convert the default value to 0.00 or cast the column to double

```
 SUM(iif(Fields!ProjectTypeID.Value = 2,cdbl(Fields!kWp.Value),0.00))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, this worked for me:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!date_break.Value = "0001-01-01",Fields!brkr_fee.Value, nothing))
```

zb

Answer (score 1):

To get the `sum` of the **kWp** of all projects of type **2**, the expression is as follows,

```
=IIf(Fields!ProjectTypeID.Value=2,sum(Fields!kWp.Value),0)
```

I hope this will help u.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure this will only sum the values for which this is true? Written this way round, it looks like the if will be performed first - and then return the sum of all the fields.

Comment: I tried and the result was the same as =SUM(Fields!kWp.Value)

Answer (score 0):

To get the conditional sum you can try this expression

```
=sum(IIf(Fields!balance.Value > 0,(Fields!balance.Value),0))
```

It sums only positive numbers otherwise it adds 0 to the total, you can do it wise versa.