# SSRS - Sum a column that gets its value from an IIF expression

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2008-r2

In SSRS, how would I sum a column that gets it's value from an expression?  For example...

```
Field1  |  Field2  |  Computed Field
------  |  ------  |  --------------
10      |  20      |  100 *IIF(Fields!Field1.Value > Fields!Field2.Value, 0, 100)*
40      |  20      |  0   *IIF(Fields!Field1.Value > Fields!Field2.Value, 0, 100)*
50      |  20      |  0   *IIF(Fields!Field1.Value > Fields!Field2.Value, 0, 100)*
------     ------     ---------------------
                      HOW DO I GET THETOTAL?
                      OF THIS COMPUTED FIELD
```

Things I've tried:

- Using "Add Total" in the report designer, but it is greyed out.
- Using conversion expression to convert IIF result to a numeric value, but summing the column give me an error.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840579/ssrs-total-of-iif-with-sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sum your expression and reference your dataset, for example:

`=sum(IIF(Fields!Field1.Value > Fields!Field2.Value, 0, 100),"DataSet1")`